# Present date as first day of the month

Tags: date, google-sheets, array-formulas

In Google Sheets I'm looking for an array formula to provide the first day of a month for a given date. e.g. If A1 is `1/17/12 20:30` B1 would read `1/1/12` and so on. The formula must keep the date format so that I can sort by date, on column B in this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could just "compose" a new date using the DATE formula. e.g.

```
=Date(Year(A1);Month(A1);1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me add to contribution from Henrique ...

I can use the following arrayformula in cell B1:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A:A,eomonth(A:A,-1)+1,))
```

where column A holds the dates or timestamps