# Formula to get the value for the first day of a month

Tags: google-sheets

I am having this issue every time the month changes where I have to modify my Google Spreadsheets to get the value for the first day of the current month from a table. I was wondering if it is possible to have a formula or script to automatically find the value for the first day of the current month.

My data looks like the following:

```
+---------------------+------+
|        ColA         | ColB |
+---------------------+------+
| 28/10/2012 00:19:01 |   42 |
| 29/10/2012 00:29:01 |  100 |
| 30/10/2012 00:39:01 |   23 |
| 31/10/2012 00:29:01 |    1 |
| 1/11/2012 00:19:01  |   24 |<---
| 2/11/2012 00:19:01  |    4 |
| 3/11/2012 00:19:01  |    2 |
+---------------------+------+
```

I am pretty sure the function `GoogleClock()` might help me, but I can't seem to understand how to make it detect the first day.

Any tip will be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Seems strange, but the answer lies in `EOMONTH`.

Example of skipping a month:

```
   =EOMONTH( "1/1/2000", 0)+1
   "2/1/2000"
```

You can also do year skipping:

```
   =EOMONTH( "1/1/2000", 11)+1
   "1/1/2001"
```

Hope that helps!

UPDATE: Looks like you specifically want `EOMONTH( TODAY(), -1)+1]`

Answer (score 0):

try using a combination of `and`, `today`, `day`, `month`, and `year`
Here is an example formula: `=and(month(A2)=month(today()), year(A2)=year(today()), day(A2)=1)`

[image]

Comment: Thats a good tip, maybe if I combine the day function with a way to get the current month (if not I will get every day=1 for all months) I can get it working. I will test your solution now! Thanks!

Comment: Hi! based on the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919637/google-spreadsheet-to-present-date-as-first-day-of-the-month I found the following formula to work `if(A:A,eomonth(A:A,-1)+1,)`

Comment: Are you looking for the first day of any month or the first day of the current month - where current means right now and would change wiht the current date.

Comment: Yes, it is for the current month, it will have to change each time the month changes